# Doctrine Single Table Inheritance: Join on Parent Association from child Entity not working. FOSUserBundle

Tags: database, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have classes

- IdentityUser (the user account, which extends the FOSUserBundle)
- Person ( person or user of the system which have userAccount (IdentityUser)
- Marketer ( a marketer user )

**EDIT** ( added use statements on classes )

The user account inheritated from FOSUSerBundle

```
namespace Elite\Security\Identity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as FOSUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 */
class IdentityUser extends FOSUser
{
    /**
     * @var integer The id
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
}




 namespace Elite\Common\Entity;

    use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface;
    use Elite\Common\ValueObject\PersonName;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 * @ORM\Table(name="people")
 */
class Person
{
    /**
     * @var integer The id
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     *
     * @var \Elite\Common\ValueObject\PersonName The name of the person
     *
     * @ORM\Embedded(class="Elite\Common\ValueObject\PersonName", columnPrefix=false)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @var \ The user identity of the person
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Elite\Security\Identity\IdentityUser")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_account_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $userAccount;

    public function __construct(UserInterface $account, PersonName $name)
    {
        $this->userAccount = $account;
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}


use Elite\Common\Entity\Person;
use Elite\Infrastructure\Doctrine\Adapter\Collection;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Elite\Common\ValueObject\PersonName;
/**
 * Class Marketer
 * @package Elite\Emti\Marketing
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Marketer extends Person
{
    public function __construct(UserInterface $userAccount, PersonName $name)
    {
        parent::__construct($userAccount, $name);
        $this->assignments = new Collection();
    }
}
```

now what im trying to do is 
**query** a Marketer 
**where** the userAccount's username
**is** dana

**EDIT**
here is my query

```
$doctrine = $this->container->get('doctrine');
        $em = $doctrine->getManager('inquiry');

        $qb = $doctrine->getRepository('EmtiInquiry:Marketer', 'inquiry')->createQueryBuilder('m');
        $dana = $qb->join('m.userAccount', 'account')
            ->where('account.username = :username')
            ->setParameter('username', 'dana')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getSingleResult();
```

but I dont get results or error like

```
[Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException]                                          
  [Semantical Error] line 0, col 91 near 'username = :': Error: Class Elite\S  
  ecurity\Identity\IdentityUser has no field or association named username     



  [Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException]                                          
  SELECT u FROM Elite\Emti\Inquiry\Marketer u INNER JOIN u.userAccount accoun  
  t WHERE account.username = :username
```

Comment: can you show your query !!

Comment: @HajriAymen I made an edit to show the query

Comment: Show your `use`-block.

Comment: Get a look at IdentityUser are you sure that you are linking to this : 

 use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User aFOSUser;
Then try to add this to IdentityUser and try again :

 public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }

Comment: actually IdentityUser is extending `FOS\UserBundle\Model\User` 
I made an edit to include use statements on my post